# Overview over all vector images in drawables

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Does Android Studio (or perhaps some other application/method of viewing) support viewing all the vector images in the `drawables` folder so that you have an overview over them all?
My issue is that I have hundreds of vector images in there, and I don't know anymore if I've imported certain icons or not and in order to find out I need to either go through them individually or search (guess) them by name.
Is there a simpler and quicker way? Some plugin perhaps ?!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no Android Studio plugin to preview vectors massively, but you could create your own "previewer activity" temporarily to retrieve all the desired folder (drawable folder or a dedicated asset folder for all your vectors).

Maybe something like this would work (I didn't test it, and probably vectors will need to be handled in a more specific way, yet it could lead you the right path):

```
AssetManager mgr = context.getAssets();
String[] files = mgr.list("images");
InputStream ist = null;
ArrayList<Drawable> vectorDrawables = new ArrayList<>();

for (String file : files) {
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(mgr.open(file), null);
    vectorDrawables.add(d);
}
```

Then put the list into a grid view or something you prefer to get a quick visualization of all your vectors.

Comment: That's not a bad idea in fact ... It's a bit of overkill, but yeah, not a bad idea at all.